# Understanding getActiveDocumentContext() function from rstudioapi package

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to understand what the function getActiveDocumentContext() is supposed to do. When I run it in my console I obtain the following output,

```
> getActiveDocumentContext()
Document Context: 
- id:        '#console'
- path:      ''
- contents:  <1 rows>
Document Selection:
- [1, 1] -- [1, 1]: ''
```

When I read the documentation related to the function

> **Details**
>
> The selection field returned is a list of document selection objects.
>   A document selection is just a pairing of a document range, and the
>   text within that range.
>
> **Value**
>
> A list with elements:
>
> id    The document ID. path   The path to the document on disk.
>   contents  The contents of the document. selection A list of selections.
>   See Details for more information.

Which makes me deduce that the return is the pointing to the console with the path being a white space and some sort of document and text within the document.

However when I run this function in a debug mode inside a function the returns are different. 
[image]

Is this due to the scope being different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of `getActiveDocumentContext` as providing information on where the user's cursor is (i.e. the pane with focus).

If the user happens to have their cursor in the R console instead of in a source editor, you'll get information about the R console instead. That's why you always see "console" when you run it at the console.

It's designed mostly to help with add-ins, which often operate on the current editing tab and/or the selection made inside it. See for example this one, which uses `getActiveDocumentContext` to help you write markdown: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/remedy

If you run `getActiveDocumentContext` while debugging, or at the R console, you're not going to get a helpful result. You might consider breaking your debugger *after* you've queried for the document context, so that the debugger doesn't put focus in the console and lose the context.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! This was helpful. I did find the code in one of the addins that I was trying to understand!

Comment: To add to that, as far as I can tell, the only way to test the add-ins is to install the package that contains them. You could create an add-in such as `MyAddin <- function() {context <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext(); print(context)}`, install it, highlight some text, and then run the add-in to see what `getActiveDocumentContext` does.